# Group with presentation $\langle x,y \ | \ x^2, y^2 \rangle$ is generated by $2$ elements of order $2$

Tags: group-theory, free-groups

Could you tell me how  to prove that a group with presentation $\langle x,y \ | \ x^2, y^2 \rangle$ is generated by $2$ elements of order $2$?

I know it's infinite, because we will have infinitely many combinations of this kind : $xyxyxyxyxyx...$,$yxyxyxyx...$ (there will be both forms there, right?) because we don't assume in the presentation that it is abelian. If we did, we would have $xyx^{-1}y^{-1}=1$ there, next to $x^2=y^2=1$, wouldn't we?

However, I don't know how to (formally) prove that this group is generated by two elements of order $2$.

Could you help?

Thank you.

Comment: It is so by the very definition.

Comment: Well, I thought so at first, but it is a separate question in my book, so I thought it needed more explanation. What about the group's order? Am I right to assume that there will be two forms of products?

Comment: The group will indeed be infinite. It is defined to be "the group generated by the two elements $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ both have order $2$, and satisfying no further relations".

Comment: Another way to write your group is $\;C_2 * C_2=\;$ the free product of two cyclic groups of order two, and it is also known as the infinite dihedral group.

Comment: It is not quite true to say that it is true by definition, because the definition says that it is "the group generated by $x$ and $y$ such that $x$ and $y$ have order dividing 2 and satisfy no further relations". To prove that $x$ and $y$ really do have order $2$ (rhather than $1$), it suffices to exhibit any group whatsoever that really is generated by two elements of order $2$, since that will be a quotient group of the group we are discussing. You could take the Klein 4-group, for example.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't quite see what you mean. Klein 4-group $= C_2 \times C_2$. How does that help here?

Comment: By the way. In order to prove that my group is isomorphic to semidirect product of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $C_2$ I need to find a homomorphism between $C_2$ and $Aut(\mathbb{Z}$, which is $1 \rightarrow -id$ and $0 \rightarrow id$. My question is - we consider the semidirect product with addition, don't we?

Comment: @DerekHolt Ahh, that is a good point. Martin: We consider $\mathbb{Z}$ as a group with addition, but the composition on $C_2$ is multiplication.

Comment: So how can we define $x$ and $y$ by means of $(z, 0), \ (z,1)$? Will $(z,1)(z,0) = (z-z, 1) = (0,1)$?

Comment: Yes (and more generally, $(x,1)(y,0) = (x-y,1)$).

Comment: All right. What about the order of $a$ and $b$? How can I prove it is $2$? I don't understand the quotient group approach. Could you explain that to me?

Comment: I am not sure what part is giving you problems. Do you see why it will be enough to show that the group now constructed is generated by two elements of order $2$?

Comment: No. I don't. I think I see that Klein 4 group is a quotient group here but why does that prove that the orders =2?

Comment: My question did not relate directly to Derek's hint about such a group. Do you see how to show that there is a homomorphism from the group mentioned in the question to the one you have constructed from $\mathbb{Z}$ and $C_2$?

Comment: Would it suffice to set $x = (z,1)(z,0)$ and $y = (z, 1)$? Their orders equal $2$.

Comment: Yes, assuming $z\neq 0$, but why write the first one in such a complicated way?

Comment: You are right, $x=(0,1)$ is much better. Are you sure it is everything, does it prove that the orders are $2$, not $1$?

Comment: Do you see that $(0,1)\neq (0,0)$?

Comment: Yes, I do. I'm sorry, it's very late. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

First it is certainly the case the group is generated by two elements, $x,y$ are generators.  The only question is whether or not those two elements actually have order 2. One would expect this to be true, since the relations have no letters in common, but it is something to show. A way to do this, as mentioned by by Derek Holt in the comments, is to give an example of an explicit group that is the homomorphic image of $\langle x,y \mid x^2,y^2 \rangle$. The abelianization (a very useful trick in the field) presents such an example, this group is the Klein four group which can be seen as the group $$\{x\mapsto x,x \mapsto -x,x \mapsto 1/x, x\mapsto -1/x\}$$ with fuctional composition, and note that $x\mapsto -x$ and $x\mapsto 1/x$ generate the group and both satisfy $$(x\mapsto -x)^2=x\mapsto x,\quad (x\mapsto 1/x)^2=x \mapsto x$$ so is the homomorphic image of the group and these images have order two. So, $x,y$ must have order two.